# How to do regular expression search using lucene.Net

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I m using lucene.Net version 3.0.3. I want to do regular expression search. I tried the following code:

```
// code

String SearchExpression = "[DM]ouglas";

const int hitsLimit = 1000000;

//state the file location of the index
string indexFileLocation          = IndexLocation;
Lucene.Net.Store.Directory dir = Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory.Open(indexFileLocation);

//create an index searcher that will perform the search
Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher searcher = new Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher(dir);

var analyzer = new WhitespaceAnalyzer();

var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, new[] {                 
            Field_Content, }, analyzer);

Term t = new Term(Field_Content, SearchExpression);
RegexQuery scriptQuery = new RegexQuery(t);

string s = string.Format("{0}", SearchExpression);

var query = parser.Parse(s);

BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
booleanQuery.Add(query, Occur.MUST);

var hits = searcher.Search(booleanQuery, null, hitsLimit, Sort.RELEVANCE).ScoreDocs;


foreach (var hit in hits)
{
    var hitDocument = searcher.Doc(hit.Doc);

    string contentValue = hitDocument.Get(Field_Content);
}

// end of code
```

When I try to search with patten `"Do*uglas"`, I get the results.

But if I search with the pattern `"[DM]ouglas]"` it is giving me the following error:

```
"Cannot parse '[DM]ouglas': Encountered " "]" "] "" at line 1, column 3. Was expecting one of: "TO" ... <RANGEIN_QUOTED> ... <RANGEIN_GOOP> ...".
```

I also tried doing simple search pattern like `".ouglas"` which should give me results, as I have `"Douglas"` in my text content.

Does anyone know how to do regular expression search using lucene.Net version 3.0.3?

Answer (score 3):

The StandardQueryParser does not support regular expressions at all.  It is, instead, attempting to interpret that portion of the query as a range query.

I you wish to use regexes to search, you will need to construct a [`RegexQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/contrib-regex/org/apache/lucene/search/regex/RegexQuery.html) manually.  Note, that `RegexQuery` performance tends to be poor.  You might be able to improve it by switching from `JavaUtilRegexCapabilities` to `JakartaRegexpCapabilities`.

Comment: Thanks femToRgon. I tried the solution that u mentioned. I manually constructed RegexQuery and it is working properly.

Comment: Hello femToRgon, I got a big performance problem when I was using regex search, Can you tell me what is switching from JavaUtilRegexCapabilities to JakartaRegexpCapabilities? or How Can I implement it on C#?